# Select by location and copy features to new shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3

I have been asked to select point features that fall into a polygon in its own shapefile then copy the points selected to a new shapefile. There are around 300 shapefiles with an indiviidual polygon. Although only a very beginnner in python i thought it would be possible to automate the process.

I based my script of one found on this site but cannot get it too work. Im not sure if it is fit for purpose or not.

We are using arcmap 9.3 so no arcpy unfortunately.

```python
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...
Layer_A = sys.argv[1] # polygon
Layer_B = sys.argv[2] # points
outfolder = sys.argv[3]
basename = sys.argv[4]

# create search Cursor that ref the features in layer B
rows = gp.searchcursor(Layer_B)
row = rows.next()


# Create a numbering system for new output files
filenum = 0 

while row:
    # Report a message back to the user about progress
    gp.addmessage("Creating Selection #" + str(filenum) + " from " + Layer_A)

    # Create a feature layer to cycle through selection features
    fidvalue = row.GetValue("FID")
    gp.MakeFeatureLayer(Layer_B,"cursor_lyr","FID =" + str(fidvalue))

    # Process: Select Layer By Location...
    gp.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Layer_A, "INTERSECT", "cursor_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")

    outname = outfolder + "\\" + basename + str(filenum)
    # Process: Copy Features...
    gp.CopyFeatures_management(Layer_A, outname, "", "0", "0", "0")

    #iterate the output file number
    filenum = filenum + 1

    #go to next row
    row = rows.next
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? if you just post a lot of code, and expect people to debug it, you are not going to get answers.

Comment: Hi sorry, i really dont know where i am stuck, the script runs yet produces no results just a blank shapefile, I imagine either the MakeFeatureLayer part is incorrect or the outname part,

Comment: I assume you are using a shapefile or DBF since you have an FID column. Your column name in your where clause needs to be in quotes:  gp.MakeFeatureLayer(Layer_B,"cursor_lyr","\"FID\" =" + str(fidvalue))

Comment: Also, your very last line should be:  row = rows.Next()

Comment: i believe i am a step closer this is my error now

Creating Selection #0 from Roecliffe_address
Creating Selection #1 from Roecliffe_address
<class 'arcgisscripting.ExecuteError'>: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Output Layer: Dataset cursor_lyrs already exists.
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).

Failed to execute (selctandcopy).

Comment: Note that my comments are all information contained in the ArcGIS tool help files. The real answer to your question lies in effective coding workflow. Part of the process is looking up the documentation on each tool--especially if you are having problems--and making sure you know what all the parameters are and how it all works together. It is all there.

Comment: Ok ill go back through it all. Thankyou though

Comment: Ok i have got it too work. with gp.OverWriteOutput = 1

thankyou for your help

Comment: @rsimpspon - you should mark this answered and correct your code to show the answer.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - As a new coder, you will have much better luck de-bugging your code if you include error handlers. http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=849&pid=839&topicname=Error_handling_with_Python

```
import sys
import traceback
try:

    # Your indented code goes here

except arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:
    msgs = gp.GetMessage(0)
    msgs += gp.GetMessages(2)
    gp.AddError(msgs)
    print msgs
except:
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = tbinfo + "\n" + str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value)
    gp.AddError(pymsg)
    print pymsg
```